# What could be causing ENMTML occurrence data problem - undefined columns selected?

Tags: r, error

Absolutely loving the ENMTML package for really making thoughtful choices for ecological niche modeling! Until I came across this problem with a single species occurrence dataset that I just can't figure out:

My occurence data is a tab delimited text file of three columns with species name, x, and y data with 561 unique records (first three shown below).

I've already thinned the data down to less than my predictor pixel resolution, and I set min_occ to 25, but when I run my code, all records are removed.

The error I then get is: Error in `[.data.frame`(occ, , c(sp, x, y)) : undefined columns selected

Any ideas of where I'm going wrong?

Source code and occurence data:

```
ENMFullV <- ENMTML(pred_dir = "F:/ENM/PredictorsFY",
proj_dir= NULL,
result_dir= "F:/ENM/ENMFullV",
occ_file = "F:/ENM/SpurgeThin.txt",
sp = "sp",
x = "x",
y = "y",
min_occ = 25,
thin_occ=NULL,
eval_occ=NULL,
colin_var = c(method = 'VIF'),
imp_var=TRUE,
pseudoabs_method = c(method='ENV_CONST'),
pres_abs_ratio = 1,
part = c(method='BOOT', replicates = '5', proportion = '0.7'),
save_part = TRUE,
save_final = TRUE,
algorithm = c('SVM', 'RDF', 'MXD', 'GLM', 'MLK'),
thr = c(type='MAX_KAPPA'),
msdm= NULL,
ensemble=c(method = c('SUP'), metric = 'Kappa'),
extrapolation=FALSE,
cores=6)
```

occurrence data example, first few rows:
[image]

Comment: Is this the `ENMTools` package? I can't see an `ENMTML` package on CRAN. Once `ENMTools` is downloaded and installed I guess I'll know...nope. Can't be that package. Can you edit and update us?

Comment: I guess its this off-CRAN package: https://github.com/andrefaa/ENMTML

Comment: Yep, it is from that/this package: https://github.com/andrefaa/ENMTML.

Answer (score 0):

Sp name should be just one word. Name it "Sp"
and put these "Sp" "x" "y"